# Questions about a scene in the 2009 Star Trek movie

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

I am currently watching it right now and I was wondering, when they beamed Kirk and Sulu back up from falling onto the Vulcan planet, wouldn't they still have died? Since the speed they were falling before they were beamed? Also, wouldn't the gravitational pull from the singularity (Black Hole) be too strong for Spock to walk on the planet, let alone run?

Comment: If you have two distinct questions, you should ask them as two questions, not one.

Comment: Insert *handwaving* here!

Comment: Related http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39295/in-star-trek-does-the-transporter-conserve-the-momentum-of-transported-objects

Comment: The question about the transporter has already been answered here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39295/in-star-trek-does-the-transporter-conserve-the-momentum-of-transported-objects

Comment: Welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. It seems you have two questions actually, rather than one. It looks like your first question [has already been answered](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39295/). Perhaps you can make a new question out of the second question?

Comment: Relevant: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotTheFallThatKillsYou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transporter [does not conserve the momentum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39295/in-star-trek-does-the-transporter-conserve-the-momentum-of-transported-objects) of the transported, so the speed they were going at is irrelevant.

Comment: Except that when they land, they land with a thump. So clearly some momentum was preserved.

Comment: Here is the (timestamped) [relevant part of the scene](https://youtu.be/QGNfrNJZin4?t=1m15s). The "thump" is not due to any conserved momentum (they would likely be injured or killed if that were the case), and is instead a result of gravity on the ship pulling them down, normally.

Comment: It's been accepted as the answer (because it's correct), but go ahead and downvote it (you probably already have) seeing as you disagree.

Comment: I've downvoted for a couple of reasons. First, I don't agree with the premise (as I've mentioned above) and secondly, it's a link-only answer. If the other question gets deleted or the URL changes, your answer becomes worthless.

Comment: Your disagreement with the premise is completely false, and has already been refuted, without an appropriate counter-argument. The "link-only" answer is completely acceptable reason for downvoting my answer, I did not know about this particular detail, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Either way, the question has been closed as a dupe. On to the next one... ***chon tagh yInISQo'!***

Comment: @Valorum google gives me nothing helpful( on mobile). What does that bold text mean?

Comment: @1252748 - Try Bing Translate :-)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part in the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek.html) is here

> TIGHT ON CHEKOV as he struggles to lock onto them -- BEEP!
>
> **CHEKOV:** *Compensating gravitational pull and...*
>
> GOTCHA!
>
> He HITS A BUTTON and --   140   EXT.   VULCAN SURFACE
>
> 5 FEET BEFORE THEY HIT THE GROUND, KIRK AND SULU DEMATERIALIZE!
>
> INT. ENTERPRISE - TRANSPORTER BAY
>
> AND REMATERIALIZE, SLAMMING DOWN ON THE TRANSPORTER PADS, HARD AND
>   PAINFUL, BUT SAFE! Transporter engineers GAPE in utter amazement and
>   relief -- Chekov, sweating, laughs. Kirk and Sulu get their bearings,
>   peeling themselves up, at stunned whispers

So there you go. He **compensated for it**, presumably in much the same way that the transporter makes allowances for the ship moving at a different speed from the planet below.